# Insert space before capital letters in variable label in Stata

Tags: string, stata

I have a Stata data set with mangled variable labels so that the label "Random Uniform Variable" is compressed to "RandomUniformVariable". I can recover the correct variable label by replacing a capital letter by a space and the capital letter.

I would like to fix this programmatically, mostly out of curiosity at this point. I have a start, but the extended function `: piece #1 of "string"` does **words**, not **letters**. Is there a way to do this?

```
clear
set obs 2001
generate var = runiform()
label variable var "RandomUniformVariable"

local name : variable label var
local i : strlen local name
display "`i'"
forvalues j = 1/`i' {
    display "`j'"
    local l : piece `j' of "`name'", nobreak
    display "`l'"
}
```

Comment: You can use standard Stata expressions with the `local` command, so `local l = substr("\`name'",\`j',1)` will work. And `strlen` did not work for me, I changed that to `length`. Neither of these solves your ultimate problem, but you might be able to get farther along now.

Comment: @WilliamLisowski - `strlen` works for me. Maybe I should have added that I'm on Stata 14? Roberto offers a great solution below. Rather than looping over the letters in the word, checking for caps, then adding a space, he loops over the capital letters and adds a space. Never knew about `creturn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brute force works:

```
clear
set more off

local teststr "RandomUniformVariable"

forvalues i = 1/26 {
    local letter : word `i' of `c(ALPHA)'
    local teststr : subinstr local teststr "`letter'" " `letter'"
}

display trim("`teststr'")
```

Comment: Very clever. Thanks! Did not know about `creturn`.